# How made ion-col expand the text over the col

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-grid

I want to the col-8 expand a text an dont center:

```
<ion-row style="height: 100%;">
  <ion-col col-2>
      <!--<ion-img class="img-menu" src="../../assets/imagen/m-lista.png" routerLink="/datospersonales"></ion-img> -->
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col col-8>
      <p class="titulo-opcion">Venta Nueva</p>
      <p>Permite el ingreso de Proyectos a clientes Nuevos o Existentes</p>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col col-2>
      <!--<ion-img class="img-menu" src="../../assets/imagen/m-flechita.png"></ion-img>-->
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

But the image 
[image: SNAP]
Show all the text center I want the first column keep 2 and 8 the center and 2 last one,

Comment: I thought the `col-8` type directives were from Ionic3 - are you sure you have tagged this question correctly? The column isn't "centered", its just got two columns on each side. I think you are going to have to try again and explain more clearly what you want. Draw a diagram. Make a spreadsheet and take a screenshot if you don't have art skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have said it sounds like you want this:

```
<ion-row style="height: 100%;">
  <ion-col>
      <p class="titulo-opcion">Venta Nueva</p>
      <p>Permite el ingreso de Proyectos a clientes Nuevos o Existentes</p>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

But I think you haven't worded it exactly so maybe this won't be the answer.

As I commented above please rewrite your question if this doesnt solve it.

Comment: thanks, if this helped please could you upvote as well otherwise, for some reason, StackOverflow set it up so that it doesn't count towards my Ionic4 badge.